# Cannot access a certain URL, everything else works fine

Tags: networking, router, dns

I've been experiencing a weird issue with my network. Everything worked fine until three days ago where, for no particular reason, I stopped having access to only one, certain website. [This](http://www.socomic.gr/) is the url of the site. Every time I try to access it I get an `err_connection_timed_out`. But, as my colleagues and the [relevant sites](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/socomic.gr.html) inform me, this particular site is up and running. As I said, everything else works perfectly, except this site.

This problem is persistent throughout *every browser*, including my mobile phone. The steps I have taken so far:

1. Cleared cookies and cache of every browser
2. Rebooted PC, Mobile Phone and Router
3. Changed my default DNS server to OpenDNS
4. Tried reaching the DNS address of the site (http://212.111.43.11) to no avail
5. Run the following commands:

> ```
> ipconfig /flushdns
> ipconfig /registerdns
> ipconfig /release
> ipconfig /renew
> ```

Also, when I run the `nslookup` command I get a weird response. First, let's examine the response of a "normal" website:

[image]

Now, the response I get when I nslookup this website:

[image]

Is this entry normal?

Also, this is the result of `PATHPING`:

[image]

The problem persists after all these steps. Indeed, if I try to access the site through my mobile phone using the data network (3G/4G) it works. Yet, when I switch to WiFi I get the stated above problem. The problem must be router related. I was certain that the DNS change would resolve it but alas.

What could be the cause of this problem and how can I resolve it?

My router is ZXV10 W300, if it makes any difference.

---

**Interesting Findings**:

So, after [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill)'s answer I contacted my ISP. They provided me with an indirect solution. I changed my username in my router's settings from xxxx@otenet.gr to xxxx@ipv6ote.gr. This results to a different path when I type `pathping` and as a result I have access to the website.

The interesting part is the following: I googled the address that gets stuck (62.75.5.177) and I stumbled upon this [link](https://lists.cypherpunks.ca/pipermail/otr-dev/2015-December/002413.html) from a mailing list that suggests that we have a case of DNS poisoning. According to the mail:

> "We suspect there is selective hijacking of this site going on. Of
>   course, the man-in-the-middle happens only when an HTTP connection is
>   used. When HTTPS is enforced, for example through HTTPS Everywhere,
>   the connection is not possible in the man-in-the-middled networks and
>   the connection is refused."

Of course, I informed my ISP about it.

Comment: To me, this looks like a possible IPv6 issue. Can you access http://ipv6.google.com ?

Comment: No, I can't but that's because I have IPv4.

Comment: What happens if you try loading with IP address `http://212.111.43.11`?

Comment: If you cannot connect to the IP of that website, as DavidPostill suggested, it's likely your ISP that your router is connected to has some problems.  Sometimes it's never your fault but the ISP's.

Comment: @DavidPostill I already tried that to no avail. I get `err_connection_timed_out`. I forgot to mention it. I've edited my question to include it.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide the output from `PATHPING 212.111.43.11`?

Comment: to expand on AndrejaKo's comment. Yes, that looks perfectly normal. You look up which address(es) that site uses and you get two answers. One for its IPv6 address and one for its legacy IPv4 address. Now there are two options: 1) You only support the old IPv4 protocol and that happens to be down on that website. (Which means that you still should be able to access it ove IPv6, or ping6 its address), or your configuration **only** tries IPv6 and that is somehow broken. In which case all IPv6 website should fail. (which are a few).

Comment: Indeed, my idea was that maybe there's IPv6 that seems to be working, but is broken, since the DNS server is fe80::1.

Comment: @DavidPostill Edited accordingly.

Comment: @Hennes Just tried visiting other IPv6 sites. They work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I stopped having access to only one, certain website `http://www.socomic.gr/`

> [image]

There is 100% packet loss between hops 5 and 6 in your `pathping` output.

This shows that there is a problem with the connection between  `62.75.3.21` and `62.75.5.177` and your packets are not getting all the way to `212.111.43.11`.

From https://whois.domaintools.com/62.75.3.21:

`62.75.0.0 - 62.75.31.255` belongs to Greece Athens Oteglobe - Ote Global Solutions Sa

[image]

Only Oteglobe can fix this problem. An email to `noc@oteglobe.gr` may help get this fixed ...

Comment: The problem is solved after contacting my ISP. I've included in my question some interesting findings.

Comment: @Aventinus Nice question update! Unfortunately I can only upvote the question once ;)